# Updating cursor after filtering BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview

So I've got a listView which will display all audio files from external storage. I'm using BaseAdapter and I can filter it with a editText. The problem is for example if audio file named "Argon" is on the first place and if I filter the listview and audio file named "Camera" comes on the first place, it would still play the Argon if I click on the Camera.

[image]

[image]

---

OnItemClickListener :

```
 songView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        music_column_index = musicCursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                musicCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String filename = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);
                Intent person = new Intent();
                Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
                backpack.putString("arnswer", filename);
                person.putExtras(backpack);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Getting the songs :

```
 public void getSongList() {

        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri;
             musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
         musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Filtering BaseAdapter with EditText :

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        getSongList();
        final SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEt);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                songAdt.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: do not use `BaseAdapter`, your data model is sqlite db based so use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: the **whole** working code using built-in `SimpleCursorAdapter` + `EditText` filtering + `OnItemClickListener` takes exactly 40 lines of code, you have the choice

Comment: I just updated my code and the list works fine but it doesn't filter, here's the code https://codeshare.io/auLXt

Comment: `Uri uri` is wrong when constraint is not null, you need just musicUri with some `selection` and `selectionArgs`

Comment: and never in the future use any ArrayAdapter/BaseAdapter when your data comes from sqlite db, never